# Convert a JSON array to a bash array of strings

Tags: json, bash, jq

How do I parse a json array of objects to a bash array with those objects as strings?

I am trying to do the following:

```
CONVO=$(get_json_array | jq '.[]')
for CONVERSATION in $CONVERSATIONS
do
    echo "${CONVERSATION}"
done
```

But the echo prints out lines instead of the specific objects.
The format of the object is:

```
{ "key1":"value1", "key2": "value2"}
```

and I need to pass it to an api:

```
api_call '{ "key1":"value1", "key2": "value2"}'
```

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/630274/42620 for a way to convert a json array to a bash array, then use normal shell looping.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The problem is that `jq` is still just outputting lines of text; <s>you can't necessarily preserve each array element as a single unit. That said, as long as a newline is not a valid character in any object,</s> you can still output each object on a separate line.

```
get_json_array | jq -c '.[]' | while read object; do
    api_call "$object"
done
```

Under that assumption, you could use the `readarray` command in `bash` 4 to build an array:

```
readarray -t conversations < <(get_json_array | jq -c '.[]')
for conversation in "${conversations[@]}"; do
    api_call "$conversation"
done
```

Comment: +1. Re: "as long as a newline is not a valid character in any object": Since these are JSON objects, that's not a concern.

Comment: Ah, I was under the mistaken assumption that a newline could appear in a hash value, but it looks like they are required to be encoded as `\n`.

Comment: If you use `jq -j` instead of `jq -r`, there's no separator added by JQ itself, so you can add your own (such as NUL literals) from your jq code.

Comment: Just want to point out that the iteration variable have to be called the same in loop header and body (`conversion` vs. `conversation`). Can't improve the answer as the change is as little as 2 characters and StackOverflow expects at least 6 characters to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution without loops:

```bash
json=$(jq -c ".my_key[]"  ./my-file.json)
json_without_quotes=$(echo ${json//\"/""})
declare -a all_apps_array=($(echo $json_without_quotes | tr "\n" " "))
```

Comment: Instead of second line you can use `jq  -r` which prints raw JSON (discards quotes).

Comment: doesn't work if there are spaces.

Comment: A one-line solution would be `declare -a all_apps_array =($(jq -r ". my_key[]" ./my-file.json | tr "\n" " "))`

Answer (score 1):

Credit for this approach goes to [@ingernet](https://ingernet.github.io/bash/jq/json/2020/04/16/json-array-bash-array.html). No `jq` required. This uses sed to remove `[`, `]`, and `,`, leaving a space between so it can be wrapped with ().

```bash
newArray=( $(echo $jsonArrayString | sed -e 's/\[//g' -e 's/\]//g' -e 's/\,/ /g') );
```

Comment: This is severely buggy. If your string is `"foo * bar"`, the `*` will be replaced with a list of filenames, and that's just the first of many problems that came to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Also another option without having to loop.

```
jq -c ".response[]"  "${file}" | sed 's/[{|}]//g' | tr ',' '\n' | sed 's/"//g' | awk -F":" '{print toupper($1)":"$2}'
```

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

This should convert a json array to a bash array regardless of the contents of the json entries. I needed it to pass a list of files to a linter inside of a github action. It was important to make a single call to the linter rather than one call per file to get the output I needed. It works in bash 3.2

```
count=$(jq length <<< "$pr_files")
declare -a files=()
for (( i=0; i < count; i++ ))
do
    file=$(jq -r ".[$i]" <<< "$pr_files")
    files+=( "$file" )
done
```