# Read Json array with JQ

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

On my project I generate a json file here is an example (only one index):

```
[
    {
        "aaa": "lklklk",
        "bbb": "uiop",
        "kkk": "zeez",
        "lll": 3,
        "_source": {
          "element1": "zzzz",
          "element2": "eeee",
          "element3": "hhhhh",
          "element4": "jjjjjj",
          "@timestamp": "2019-07-31T08:32:45.000Z",
          "element5": "1",
          "element6": "6768",
          "element7": "gggg",
          "element8": "ppppp"
        },
        {
        "aaa": "lklklk",
        "bbb": "uiop",
        "kkk": "zeez",
        "lll": 3,
        "_source": {
          "element1": "zzzz",
          "element2": "eeee",
          "element3": "hhhhh",
          "element4": "jjjjjj",
          "@timestamp": "2019-07-31T08:32:45.000Z",
          "element5": "1",
          "element6": "6768",
          "element7": "gggg",
          "element8": "ppppp"
        },
]
```

I use this command

```
var1=$(jq '.['$cpt'] | ._source .element1' file.json)
```

and I can receive my value, however I receive this error:

> jq error Cannot index number with number

I already try with

```
var1=$(jq '.[] | ._source .element1' file.json)
```

but I receive all data and I need to receive the data by index.

Here is my bash code:

```
while (($verification!=1))
  do
          elementa[$cpt]=$(jq '.['$cpt'] | ._source .element1' $File.json)
          elementb[$cpt]=$(jq '.['$cpt'] | ._source .element2' $File.json)
          elementc[$cpt]=$(jq '.['$cpt'] | ._source .element3' $File.json)
          elementd[$cpt]=$(jq '.['$cpt'] | ._source .element4' $File.json)
          elemente[$cpt]=$(jq '.['$cpt'] | ._source .element5' $File.json)
          elementf[$cpt]=$(jq '.['$cpt'] | ._source .element6' $File.json)
          elementg[$cpt]=$(jq '.['$cpt'] | ._source .element7' $File.json)
          elementh[$cpt]=$(jq '.['$cpt'] | ._source ."@timestamp"' $File.json)
          elementi[$cpt]=$(jq '.['$cpt'] | ._source .element8' $File.json)
done
```

for each line I receive the same error :/
Do you know why I have this error?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there really an array in the JSON file? It needs to be like `[ { ... }, { ... }, ...]`

Comment: Show how the file looks with multiple elements.

Comment: Hello yes sorry, here is multiple element. I updated the post.

Comment: The sample input is still invalid JSON. You could use jq to diagnose the problems [plural!], but feel free to use an online service such as jsonlint.com :-)

Answer (score 3):

[EDIT: This A has been updated to reflect an update to the Q.]

1. The given input is (still) not valid JSON, but after fixing it in accordance with the description of the problem, you could you use this jq filter to extract .element1:

   ```
   .[0]._source.element1
   ```

   To extract all the items in the first ._source, you could simply write:

   ```
   .[0]._source[]
   ```

   Or if you want to absolutely sure about the ordering:

   ```
   .[0]._source[ "element1","element2","element3","element4","@timestamp","element5","element6","element7","element8"]
   ```

   Either way, extracting all the items at once (at least for each group) is probably the way to go, even if it really is necessary to process each separately outside jq.
2. The line:

   ```
   var1=$(jq '.['$cpt'] | ._source .element1' file.json)
   ```

   is a jumble (as are all the other lines like it).  Evidently you meant something like this:

   ```
   var1=$(jq ".[\"$cpt\"] | ._source .element1" file.json)
   ```

   as `$cpt` is elsewhere evidently a bash variable.  Even if that is what you intended, though, it would be better to pass in the bash variable in some other way, e.g. if $cpt is an integer:

   ```
   var1=$(jq --argjson cpt "$cpt" '.[$cpt] | ._source .element1' file.json)
   ```

   Of course this still does not address the mismatch with the sample JSON.
3. There are many SO Q&As about populating bash variables with values from a single run of jq.  See e.g. 
   [jq - return json as bash array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45534673/jq-return-json-as-bash-array)

Comment: Hi De pointe, thank you for this detail :) I would like to have one element in one var. Because I need to verify different elements after that. SO how can I put one element in one var ? I need to extract data by data and by index.

Comment: I receive always the same error:

jq: error (at file.json:1): Cannot index number with number
jq: error (at file.json:2): Cannot index number with number

Comment: If $cpt is an integer, the simplest would be to use `--argjson` instead of `--arg`.

Comment: Hi Peak, yes and thank you for that. However the errors are always present :/ and I don't understand the problem ><

Comment: Have you fixed the JSON?  Try running `jq empty file.json`

Comment: You can see an example of my json in my first post. I tried jq empty file.json and always the same :/

Comment: FYI: I already tried with jq '.[2] | ._source .element1' file.json we receive the value but always with the same error....

Comment: The JSON in your posting is invalid!!! Fix it.  Use the error message as a guide.