# Making array from values requested with jq

Tags: arrays, bash, scripting, jq

I am trying to make an array with Jq

My code is:

```
all='('$(cat players_temp.json | jq -r  '.item1.items[1].firstName, .item1.items[1].lastName')')'
```

It gives the output

```
$ echo $all
(Luka Modrić)

$ echo $all[1]
(Luka Modrić)[1]
```

as you can see the array does not work like an array. I was expecting this:

```
$ echo $all[1]
Modrić
```

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines as closely as possible. Here, some (possibly simplified) version of players_temp.json would be helpful.

Comment: While I don't know what your variable really looks like, notice that array element access in Bash looks like `${all[1]}`, not `$all[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

To create a bash array from jq output, see e.g. the following SO page:

[How do I convert json array to bash array of strings with jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35005893/how-do-i-convert-json-array-to-bash-array-of-strings-with-jq)

To understand why your approach failed, consider this transcript of a session with the bash shell:

```
$ all='('"Luka Modrić"')'
$ echo $all
(Luka Modrić)

$ echo $all[1]
(Luka Modrić)[1]
```

This essentailly shows that your question has nothing to do with jq at all.

If you want `$all` to be an array consisting of the two strings "Luka" and "Modrić" then you could write:

```
$ all=("Luca" "Modrić")
echo ${all[1]}
Modrić
$ echo ${all[0]}
Luca
```

Notice the correct bash syntax for arrays, and that the index origin is 0.

### Summary

1. See the above-mentioned SO page for alternative ways to create a bash array from jq output.
2. The syntax for creating a bash array from a collection of strings can be summarized by:

   ary=( v0 ... )
3. If ary is a bash array, ${ary[i]} is the i-th element, where i ranges from 0 to ${#ary[@]} - 1.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried to use the function get_json_array that mentioned in the link you provided. Unfortunately i get error 'command not found'. Am i missing something?

Comment: @Muq - Apparently so.  It's just a place-holder for a process that produces a JSON array.