# Construct a command based upon a count variable in bash

Tags: bash, yq

I want to construct a command based upon the number of groups in the  yaml file shown in the Example..

Example:

I have groups command as below which extracts the groups from the  iamIdentityMappings yaml file,

```
groups=$(yq read -j generated/identity-mapping.yaml "iamIdentityMappings.[0].groups")
```

iamIdentityMappings yaml file:

```
iamIdentityMappings:
- groups:
  - Appdeployer
  - Moregroups
  rolearn: arn:aws:iam::12345:role/eks-project-us-east-1-ppdeployer
  username: user1
```

Since there are two groups in groups array,I need to add two groups in the below command,

```
 eksctl create iamidentitymapping --cluster "$name" --region "$region" --arn "$rolearn" --group "Appdeployer" -group "Moregroups" --username "$username"
```

If there are 3 groups,then --group should be repeated 3 times in the command.

Please let me know how to do this in bash

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convery yaml array to string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62926327/convery-yaml-array-to-string-array)

Comment: What have you tried? Why/how did it not work? http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out..

```
grouparr=''
    for group in $groups; do
       echo $group
       if [[ ! $group == '-' ]]; then
          grouparr+=" --group $group "
       fi
    done
```

Comment: Always quote used variables. Also `${name}` syntax is recommended

Comment: The `for group in $groups` part can fail in weird ways if any group names contain spaces (or other whitespace) or anything that can be mistaken for a shell filename wildcard (that includes square brackets).

Comment: @Rad4: Instead of putting the values together into a **string** and rely on word splitting to tear them apart (which would fail if you have spaces in group names), I suggest that you use an **array** to collect the paramters.