# Bash: JSON Array to Bash Array of Strings

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm having a JSON file groups.json which is having data in below format -

```
[
{ "key" : "value" },
{ "key" : "value" },
{ "key" : "value" }
]
```

I need these key value pairs to a bash array of strings like this -

```
bashArray = [ { "key" : "value" }  { "key" : "value" }  { "key  : "value" } ]
```

How can I achieve this on Bash3.x?

Comment: Please add your desired output for `declare -p bashArray` to your question.

Answer (score 2):

With modern versions of bash, you'd simply use `mapfile` in conjunction with the -c option of jq (as illustrated in several other SO threads, e.g. [Convert a JSON array to a bash array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35005893/convert-a-json-array-to-a-bash-array-of-strings))

With older versions of bash, you would still use the -c option but would build up the array one item at a time, along the lines of:

```
while read -r line ; do 
  ary+=("$line")
done < <(jq -c .......)
```

#### Example

```bash
#!/bin/bash
function json {
    cat<<EOF
[
  { "key" : "value1" },
  { "key" : "value2" },
  { "key" : "value3" }
]
EOF
}

while read -r line ; do 
  ary+=("$line")
done < <(json | jq -c .[])

printf "%s\n" "${ary[@]}"
```

Output:

```
{"key":"value1"}
{"key":"value2"}
{"key":"value3"}
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Tx. Fixed.