# How can I expand a Bash array as arguments to `fswatch`?

Tags: arrays, shell, arguments, zsh, fswatch

Here are the details of my setup. I have the following files:

**config.json**

```json
{
    "paths": ["/Users/First Folder", "/Users/Second Folder"]
}
```

**test.sh**

```bash
#!/bin/zsh
monitored_paths=$(jq -r '.paths[]' config.json)
fswatch --verbose "${monitored_paths[@]}"
```

The `paths` key in the JSON array needs to be processed by `jq` and then expanded as arguments. However, when executing `test.sh`, I encounter this output:

Output:

```
start_monitor: Adding path: /Users/First Folder
/Users/Second Folder
```

My expectation is to have:

```
start_monitor: Adding path: /Users/First Folder
start_monitor: Adding path: /Users/Second Folder
```

In summary, I aim to monitor two files, but it seems only one file is being monitored. How can I resolve this issue?

EDIT:

Used exact output by request in the comments.

Comment: `monitored_paths` is not an array, it's a string.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35005893/convert-a-json-array-to-a-bash-array-of-strings for how to convert a JSON array to a bash array.

Comment: Thank you. I found out this works: `monitored_paths=("${(@f)$(jq -r '.monitoredPaths[]' config.json)}")` to read a JSON array as a bash array.

Comment: Are you using zsh ?

Comment: Why did you tag this `bash` when you're using `#!/bin/zsh`? I just spent several minutes searching the Bash Manual for `(@f)`.

Comment: Sorry, @Barmar. I found that after posting my question, and didn't know that feature wasn't available in `bash`. Will remember that in the future.

Comment: The two shells are very different. You can't say you're using one when you're actually using the other and expect useful answers.

Comment: Well @Shawn, that's part of the learning process. If I make a mistake in the design of the question, it's good to be correct. I didn't know every detail, that's why I am seeking for help since there are knowledgeable people here willing to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** Following answers were based on the `bash` tag that was originally attributed to the question; the tag has since been changed to `zsh`; I don't use `zsh` but from comments by OP:

- the `while/read` loop works in `zsh`
- the `mapfile` does not work in `zsh`

---

As mentioned in comments the current `monitored_paths` assignment populates the variable with a single (2-line) string:

```
$ typeset -p monitored_paths
declare -a monitored_paths=([0]=$'/Users/First Folder\n/Users/Second Folder')
```

Notice the embedded linefeed (`\n`) between the 2 paths.

This entire 2-line construct is fed to `fswatch` as a single path.

A couple options for populating `monitored_paths` as an array:

**while/read loop:**

```
monitored_paths=()

while read -r path
do
    monitored_paths+=("$path")
done < <(jq -r '.paths[]' config.json)
```

**mapfile:**

```
mapfile -t monitored_paths < <(jq -r '.paths[]' config.json)
```

Both of these create/populate the array:

```
$ typeset -p monitored_paths
declare -a monitored_paths=([0]="/Users/First Folder" [1]="/Users/Second Folder")
```

From here OP's current code should function as expected:

```
fswatch --verbose "${monitored_paths[@]}"
```

Comment: It seems "Philippe" is right. `fswatch` inform `start_monitor: Adding path: '/Users/First Folder'`. The single quotes shouldn't be there since the single quotes aren't part of the path.

Comment: I will do that in a second.

Comment: ok, I think I understand where you're coming from ... the `typeset -p` shows `[0]="'/Users/First Folder'"` (single and double quotes) when it should show `[0]="/Users/First Folder"` (only double quotes); the single quotes are a result of OP's `jq -r '.paths[] | @sh' config.json` so, how do you get `jq` to 'remove' both the double quotes (-4) and single quotes?

Comment: Thank you for your question and answer ! I edited my question. Regarding your concerns, I had to remove `@sh` filter (safely escapes each of the elements in the array.

Comment: I just checked and if we leave the quotes, as guessed, the monitoring process doesn't occur because those single quoted paths don't exist.

Comment: @F.Zer is right. Removing `| @sh` is enough, assuming there are no special characters (like newlines) in the paths.

Comment: ok, that's even simpler, I've update the answer with the `| @sh` removed

Comment: I upvoted, thank you for your answer. In my system, there is no `mapfile` command, so I can't test.

Comment: @F.Zer there are actually 2 answers ... did the `while/read` loop work? (I know the `while/read` loop works in `bash` but I'm not a `zsher`)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the first using `while/read`. Will test now.

Comment: You did it ! Congratulations. Now, two paths are passed to `fswatch`

Comment: Finally!!!! :-)

Comment: Yes ! Hahaha. Oh, and I can confirm that `while/read` solution works using `zsh`.

Comment: You could add `#!/bin/zsh` to your `while/read` solution to make that clear for future readers.

Comment: I presume you are using `bash 3.2` of MacOS. You can install newer bash version with `brew install bash` which should install bash in `/usr/local/bin/bash`

Comment: Yes, that's right @Philippe. I am using `bash 3.2`. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

in shell syntax from shebang of your example

```
#!/bin/zsh
typeset -a monitored_paths
jq -r '.paths[]' config.json | while read -r p; do monitored_paths+="$p"; done
fswatch --verbose $monitored_paths
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that passes a single path to `fswatch`, instead of two.

Comment: I've checked it with config from your example, it works in linux at least.
To debug: firstly run `jq -r '.paths[]' config.json`, if it shows two lines (one per path), then run `zsh -x test.sh`. Suppose it will give some hints

Comment: You are right, upvoted. Sorry about that. Not sure why (out of habit) added quotes around "$monitored_paths". Do you know why that failed ?

Comment: I mean, I called `fswatch --verbose "$monitored_paths"` like that.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice `zsh`

Comment: @F.Zer "added quotes around "$monitored_paths". Do you know why that failed?" - in this case you got a combined line of args. With double quotes just use `"${monitored_paths[@]}"`, but `$monitored_paths` is shortly

Comment: @F.Zer : The quotes are usually not relevant, since zsh does word splitting before parameter expansion. But if you use for an array the syntax with `[@]`, i.e. `"{arrayname[@]}"`, the quotes matter.