How to convert AWS CLI string array into a bash array efficiently
This is an example AWS CLI script:
taskDefs=$(aws ecs list-task-definitions --status="INACTIVE" --query="taskDefinitionArns")
echo $taskDefs
# output: ["arn:1", "arn:2", "arn:3"]

This outputs exactly the same:
echo $taskDefs[0]
# output: ["arn:1", "arn:2", "arn:3"]

I want to iterate over the results but it seems to just echo the entire array.
for value in "${taskDefs[@]}"
do
echo "value=$value" 
done
# output: value=["arn:1", "arn:2", "arn:3"]

I want it to output:
value="arn:1"


Or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/35005893/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/33950596/3001761, ...

@jonrsharpe None of these solve this problem elegantly. What is the elegant solution?

This looks identical to your other question

closed before i could post this - only because you claim no existing answers suite ... ignore if this is just more noise. cat parseme.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
vals=eval(sys.argv[1])
for val in vals:
print(""" + val + """ )
(base) hunkemoller@Z800:~/code/stackoverflow/78928789$ for v in $(./parseme.py "${taskDefs}"); do echo value="${v}"; done
value="arn:1"
value="arn:2"
value="arn:3"

Thankyou @ticktalk. I actually found a solution which is more elegant and suits specifically the context of the output of the aws cli. While everyone seems to be determined to close the question and associate my question with previous solutions,  to use a third party tool like jq is unnecessary. aws cli output can be in text. That can be wrapped in a bash array. myarray=($(awsOutputetc --output ext)). echo $myarray[0]
